# WebSphere Portal - Retain friendly URL after Portlet Action/Render call

Tags: friendly-url, websphere-portal

I have implemented friendly URL in WebSphere Portal 7.0. So lets say I have page with friendly URL "test" and a portlet added to the page. When I hit Portal URL /wps/myportal/test, the page is loaded with no junk characters(no state information). But as soon as I click on any button inside portlet(any action call to Portlet) I see that the junk characters comes back.

Is there a way to keep URL friendly all the time? How can we avoid generating junk characters on portlet action/render calls?

Note:- We have different portlets for different pages and they were developed based on different framework (Spring, Struts, JSR 286 etc)..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in 7.0 by default no, the action url is needed to tell portal what portlet to target.  What you could do is use the resourceAction and do everything rest based and avoid the action url, or set up a servlet to handle actions for the portlet and handle urls through that as well in a rest manner.

You could also redirect after the action url back to a friendly url in your portlet code

Comment: Thanks Crosstalk22. I was suspecting as much. I am thinking to use apache mod_rewrite and mod_proxy to hide those junk characters.